How can I fix the following ERC error?
I've been working on the following flexible transmission system, and I wanted to do a electrical rule check before continuing and I'm getting an error that I don't know why I'm getting. Sorry if this a very simple question but could anyone explain why I'm getting this error and how to fix it? I've simulated this exact circuit in LTspice and it works fine which is why it's confusing me.
Electrical Rules Checker Violation:

Error: Input Power pin not driven by any Output Power pins
Symbol #PWR02 Pin 1 [Power input, Line]



Actually it is not a big deal you can clear the error by adding a power flag to the pin but it is not necessary.it will not affect the circuit working.
Thank you

Unless you are planning on running simulation or see a possibility of importing Kicad projects to a different tool, this ERC error can be safely excluded.
The error comes from specifying the type of pin while making the symbol as shown here:

